# In a computer center, 4 computers must dispose of 3 workloads.

Tags: probability, statistics

In a computer center, 4 computers must dispose of 3 workloads.

How many are the possible distributions of the 3 workloads?

My book uses combinations with repetitions but I don't understand why. How can you have the same workload twice in one distribution?

Comment: Is the answer of the book $\binom43=4$?

Comment: @drhab no it's 20. it's with repetitions

Comment: The repetitions are of the computers, not the workloads. You can have one computer do more than one workload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you must find the number of sums $c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4=3$ where $c_i$ denotes the number of workloads done by computer $i$ (so $c_i$ is a nonnegative integer).

So computers are distinghuishable here and workloads are not.

With [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) we find $\binom{6}{3}=20$ possibilities.